# separate 3D matrix like numpy

Tags: matlab, numpy, matrix, 3d, 2d

I am converting numpy code to matlab. tensor is a 3D matrix of 6 x 2D matrices of the tensor components. This code appears to then split them back into those 6 separate 2D matrices.

```
gxx, gxy, gxz, gyy, gyz, gzz = tensor
```

Can I do this as eloquently in matlab?

re OmG: gxx, etc are the six tensor components of a gravity grid. xx for 2nd derivative of x in the x direction, xy is the 2nd derivative of x in the y direction, etc. Those components will be put through a simple equation to calculate the invariants which will then calculate the depth of the gravity anomaly.

Comment: what are `gxx`, `gyy`, ... exactly? please explain more about them.'

Comment: gxx, etc are the six tensor components of a gravity grid. xx for 2nd derivative of x in the x direction, xy is the 2nd derivative of x in the y direction, etc. Those components will be put through a simple equation to calculate the invariants which will then calculate the depth of the gravity anomaly.

Comment: Looks like all you need is `gxx = tensor(:,:,1); gxy = tensor(:,:,2); ...`

Answer (score 0):

As @Div-iL says, you could simply assign each variable to a slice of the 3D array:

```
tensor = rand(5,3,6); % Random data to play with

gxx = tensor(:,:,1);
gxy = tensor(:,:,2);
% etc
```

However if you *really* wanted to do it automatically you could generate a cell-array of 2D arrays (using `mat2cell`) and then assign them to variables using a [comma-separated list](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html#br2js35-7) assignment:

```
[nx,ny,nz] = size(tensor);
ca = mat2cell(tensor, nx, ny, ones(1,nz));
[gxx, gxy, gxz, gyy, gyz, gzz] = ca{:};
```

However, that all feels a bit hairy to me. If you're looking for a natively-supported one-liner (like your example) then I think you're out of luck.